# Getting a error when assigning a array via mapping

Tags: solidity

```
struct Identifier {
    string use;
    string value;
}

struct x {
 Identifier[] identifier;
}

mapping (address => x) private profiles;
```

I have the following code in a function:

```
function createProfile(x calldata user) external {

profiles[msg.sender].identifier = user.identifier;

}
```

Getting error:

UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct BlockEMRFetchandCreate.Identifier calldata[] calldata to storage not yet supported.

This is a very large contract, how do I set value efficiently.

Comment: Try changing `calldata` to `memory` in the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity doesn't allow you to copy an array of structs to storage. You have to loop through the memory/calldata array push to storage 1 by 1

For an example (since you said your x struct has multiple members), I'll rename 'x' into Profile, where Profile is

```
struct Profile {
   Identifier[] identifier;
   uint256 val1;
   uint256 val2;
}
```

Here is how you can set it to a mapping:

```
function createProfile(Profile calldata user) external {
   // create a storage reference 
   Profile storage profile = profiles[msg.sender];
   
   // store non array members
   profile.val1 = user.val1;
   profile.val2 = user.val2;

   // store length to memory to save gas
   uint256 length = user.identifier.length;
   
   // loop through array and push to storage
   for(uint256 i; i < length;) {
      // push to storage
      profile.identifier.push(user.identifier[i]);
      // iterate with unchecked to save gas
      unchecked { ++i; }
   }

}
```

Comment: Can we get a example of looping through it? In my code, it doesn't have just 1 member, it has a lot more, but just for reference.

Comment: is looping through the most optimal way?

Comment: Gave an example. Looping is the only way

Comment: Thanks, also what about double loop? should it just have two unchecked?

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145675/copying-arrays-in-solidity/145683?noredirect=1#comment164188_145683

Comment: Stuck on that double loop