# Copying arrays in Solidity

Tags: solidity

```
struct CodeableConcept {
 Coding[] coding;
 string text;
}

struct Coding {
 string code;
 string display;
 string system;
 bool userSelected;
 string version;
}

struct Identifier {
 CodeableConcept type_;
}

struct Patient {
 Identifier[] identifier 
}


mapping (address => Patient) private profiles;
```

I have the following function:

```
function createPatientProfile(Patient calldata userInput) external {

    uint256 length = userInput.identifier.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
        profiles[msg.sender].identifier.push(
            Identifier(userInput.identifier[i].assigner,
            userInput.identifier[i].period, userInput.identifier[i].system,
            userInput.identifier[i].type_, userInput.identifier[i].use,
            userInput.identifier[i].value)
        );
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
UnimplementedFeatureError: Copying of type struct Contract.Coding memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.
```

How do I create another for loop to copy everything from CodeableConcept Coding? as userInput.identifier[i].type_ is an array

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because there is no way of directly assigning values to the array of struct.

To fix this error, you can use a loop to copy each struct in the array to the storage variable one at a time.

```
function createPatientProfile(Patient calldata userInput) external {
    uint256 length = userInput.identifier.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
        Identifier storage identifier = profiles[msg.sender].identifier.push();
        identifier.type_.text = userInput.identifier[i].type_.text;
        identifier.system = userInput.identifier[i].system;
        identifier.value = userInput.identifier[i].value;
        uint256 codingLength = userInput.identifier[i].type_.coding.length;
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < codingLength; j += 1) {
            identifier.type_.coding.push(Coding(
                userInput.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].code,
                userInput.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].display,
                userInput.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].system,
                userInput.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].userSelected,
                userInput.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].version
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this fixes your issue.
Good Luck

Comment: If you still have some issues lemme know!

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know if this is efficient/optimal? is it going to take a lot of gas?

Comment: It won't take allot of gas but this is the only possible way of doing it so we have to deal with it

Comment: Can you explain 
Identifier storage identifier = profiles[msg.sender].identifier.push();

why are we pushing?

I am getting:

Contract ran out of gas. Something in the constructor (ex: infinite loop) caused gas estimation to fail. Try:

Comment: It seems the error is occuring right after

 Identifier storage identifier = profiles[msg.sender].identifier.push();

when we do:

identifier.type_.text = userInput.identifier[i].type_.text;

Comment: Lemme re check and get back to you

Comment: Hi, are there any updates?