# Solidity - Which assignment is more optimal?

Tags: solidity

```
 function createPatientProfile(Patient calldata patientProfileFromProvider) external {
    uint256 length = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
     patientProfiles[msg.sender].identifier.push(patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i]);
    }
}
```

vs

```
function createPatientProfile(Patient calldata patientProfileFromProvider) external {
    Patient storage userProfile = patientProfiles[msg.sender];
    uint256 length = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
        Identifier storage identifier = userProfile.identifier.push();
        identifier.assigner = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].assigner;
        identifier.period = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].period;
        identifier.system = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].system;
        identifier.use = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].use;
        identifier.value = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].value;
        identifier.type_.text = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.text;
        
        uint256 codingLength = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding.length;
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < codingLength; j+=1) {
            identifier.type_.coding.push(Coding(
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].code,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].display,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].system,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].userSelected,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].version
            ));
        }
        
        
    }
```

The bottom function costs 0.0357475 ETH and the top function costs 0.034~ ETH. From the thread: [Copying arrays in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/145675/copying-arrays-in-solidity/145683?noredirect=1#comment164219_145683)

Which one is preferred? Both generate same output, but should we explicitly assign struct variables or can we just push?

Comment: First, you should check the gas consumption instead of the gas price as it fluctuates over time. 
Either in remix or hardhat gas reporter.
Second the first approach is better in my opinion, but again if the later one takes less gas then it should be the approach

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a struct variable to another struct variable, a copy of the struct is made. This copy operation can be expensive, especially if the struct is large and contains nested structs or arrays. Lets compare both approaches.

### Approach 1

```js
function createPatientProfile(Patient calldata patientProfileFromProvider) external {
    uint256 length = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
     patientProfiles[msg.sender].identifier.push(patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i]);
    }
}
```

This approach simply loops through the `identifier` array in `patientProfileFromProvider` and pushes each element to the `identifier` array in the `patientProfiles` mapping for the calling `msg.sender`. This approach is simple and straightforward, but there are also some downsides to it. For example, it simply copies the entire array, including any unused elements - this can potentially result in excess gas usage (especially if the array is large). Another potential downside is that it doesn't allow for any customization or validation of the copied elements in contrast to approach 2.

### Approach 2

```js
function createPatientProfile(Patient calldata patientProfileFromProvider) external {
    Patient storage userProfile = patientProfiles[msg.sender];
    uint256 length = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier.length;
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i+=1) {
        Identifier storage identifier = userProfile.identifier.push();
        identifier.assigner = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].assigner;
        identifier.period = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].period;
        identifier.system = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].system;
        identifier.use = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].use;
        identifier.value = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].value;
        identifier.type_.text = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.text;
        
        uint256 codingLength = patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding.length;
        for (uint256 j = 0; j < codingLength; j+=1) {
            identifier.type_.coding.push(Coding(
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].code,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].display,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].system,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].userSelected,
                patientProfileFromProvider.identifier[i].type_.coding[j].version
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

With the second approach you create a `userProfile` variable to store the `identifier` array for the calling `msg.sender` - loops through the `identifier` array in `patientProfileFromProvider` - creates a new `Identifier` struct for each element -  and then assigns the values of the element to the corresponding fields.
With this way of doing it you get more customization and validation of the copied elements (and it only copies the fields that are needed). But it can be more complex and also require more gas.

### Summary

The choice between these approaches will depend on your use case (and also performance requirements). If you need to simply copy an array without modification, the first approach is probably the way to go. If you need to modify or validate the elements in a specific way, the second approach may be more appropriate.
Additionally its always a good idea to compare different approaches regarding gas measurements to check which one is more efficient.